# How to make focus on Leaflet marker with a click from another window

Tags: leaflet

I am making a project using Leaflet. I made a script which creates a map with one marker. A click on the map creates a window with the marker coordinates and I would like to be able to click on coordinates in the new window and having a focus on the marker linked to this coordinates on the map. But I have no idea on how to do it or if there is a better way to do this even after searching on Internet. You can easily launch the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body>



<div  <div id="map" style="width: 1800px; height: 1000px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox.streets',
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFyY2R1cnJlbm1hdHQiLCJhIjoiY2p4MmFmY21yMGgxZzQ5cWYzYzN5YnA3NSJ9.XAT5P6nD3KEOwvcZHEb6Kw'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    function onMapClick(e) {

        var popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>")
        .openOn(mymap);

        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'ty for helping</p>");
        myWindow.document.write(marker.getLatLng());    
        }

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);



</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "having a focus on the marker"? Does this mean pan and zoom to marker location?

Comment: Sounds like you want to [pass messages between `Window`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: Yes TomazicM , that's what i want to do

Comment: Yes IvanSanchez i would like to have a focus on makers ( from first window ) when i click on my new window markers coordinates .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want your child window to communicate with parent window, it will need some Java Script code, which is simpler to implement if you create separate page for child window.

Parent window will send `lat,lng` coordinates as arguments to child window. Child window will on click call Java Script function in parent window, with `lat,lng` parameters. This function will then `flyTo` to desired coordinates.

Parent window Java Script code modification:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>")
    .openOn(mymap);
    var lat = marker.getLatLng().lat;
    var lng = marker.getLatLng().lng;
    var myWindow = window.open('child.html?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng, "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
};

 function flyToLatLng(lat, lng) {
    mymap.flyTo([lat, lng], 15);
 };
```

Child page `child.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MsgWindow</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>This is 'MsgWindow'ty for helping</p>
<p id="latlng" style="background-color: #E5E5E5; cursor: pointer"></p>

<script>
  // quick dirty solution to get arguments lat and lng
  var lat = location.search.match(/lat=([^&]+)/)[1]; 
  var lng = location.search.match(/lng=([^&]+)/)[1];

  document.getElementById('latlng').innerHTML = lat + ', ' + lng;

  document.getElementById('latlng').addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.opener.flyToLatLng(lat, lng);
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thak you very much , it works perfectly . Since i send coordinates to child , do you think it's possible to do it for few markers with out opening a window for each ?

Comment: If answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. As per your question, I don't quite understand it. You cannot `flyTo` more than one coordinate. Or you want several of them to be within `fitBounds`?

Comment: Yes no problem i will do it.I can explain a bit what my project is to help you understand, I want on click to find the 5 nearest markers and then i want to put them in a window like you did in which you can click on them. My problem now is that i dont know how to create a child.html with 5 markers in it, which would give me a window with 5 clickable markers coordinates. I hope it is better explanation, Thank you very much for your time and help TomazicM